# Why can't ladle import its dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, ladle

I cannot run the example of the [ladle](https://github.com/tajo/ladle) website: Failed to resolve import
How can I fix that error?

Examplecode, that does not work:

```
mkdir my-ladle
cd my-ladle
yarn init --yes
yarn add @ladle/react react react-dom
mkdir src
echo "export const World = () => <p>Hey</p>;" > src/hello.stories.tsx
yarn ladle serve
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: post source of  hello.stories.tsx, try change the import if exists to import {storyUpdated} from "story-hmr"

Comment: @Oleg I now postet the hello.stories.txt, inside ther is no import

Comment: try to use example and his dependencies: https://github.com/tajo/ladle/blob/master/packages/example/package.json

Comment: @Oleg ist throws the same error, after yarn install, yarn serve

Comment: Did you check issues about it: https://github.com/tajo/ladle/issues?q=+resolve+

Comment: Ladle currently does not support running on Windows:
https://github.com/tajo/ladle/issues/67